# Can I put the cursor of a Iterator the location befor the first item after I have loop through it?

Tags: java

I have a Iterator iter,I do loop throuth it,

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
    //do somethintg
}
```

now I want to loop throuth it again,Can I put the  cursor befor the first item?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it.
What you can do is creating another instance of the Iterator.

Unlike `ResultSet` we cannot go to the first with [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well.. You can again obtain the instance of the Iterator. If you explicitly want to use the same iterator (I do not find a need though) use the `java.util.ListIterator` implementations.

**EDIT** This will help you move in both directions.

Comment: in fact,the Iterator is middle result,I deal with every item in it.the Iterator will be loop through in another place.